# Linking Peers of Peers: Replacing multiple listings of 2 link peers

Tags: variables, stata

I have data that provides the identifiers for a respondent's nominated friends. I am attempting to link 2 link away peers of peers (those who are not the respondent's friends but the respondent's friends of friends) so that I can use the 2 link away peers' characteristics as instruments for the effect of peers' outcomes and characteristics on the respondent.

I have successfully linked the identifiers of the 2 link peers but I need to replace repeated entries of those 2 link peers as missing, leaving each 2 link peer identifier observed only once. Maybe this is much easier than I've made it out to be - I'm not the sharpest nor brightest - but thus far I have failed. Below I provide a toy data set of identifiers and the steps I have attempted that work and where I'm stuck.

I provide the entire setup I have been working through but it is point number 4 in the code where I am stuck. This toy example has only 2 male and 2 female friends listed but the real data has up to 5 male and 5 female friends listed. If anyone has tips on how I can make the entire approach more general and straightforward I would appreciate hearing them.

In the data, `aid` is the person identifier; `mf1aid` is male friend 1 and so on. I need to link each friend's friends who are not `aid`'s friends to `aid`  Some of the early steps require the `vlookup` program.

These parts work, though are probably inefficient.

```
clear all
clear mata
set more off





input aid  mf1aid mf2aid ff1aid ff2aid  
      101   102     103     106    .    
      102   101     104     106    .    
      103   101     104     107   108   
      104   105     102     108   109   
      105   104     101     106   110   
      106   101     102     107   108   
      107   103      .      106   110   
      108   103     104     109   108   
      109   104     101     108   110   
      110   105     104     109   107   

end 

/* The above data is setup so that some aid's name friends who reciprocate and some
name friends who do not reciprocate the link (as in the real data).  */




/* Need to link aid's of those 2 links away from each aid 

 It must do the following:
    1. Link the friend `aid`s of each person's friends
    2. Delete the friend of friends `aid`s that are also the person's 1 link friends
    3. Delete extra counts of 2 link `aid`s that may occur if a person's friends
        are all linked to a k `aid` that is not linked to i.        
    4. Delete self from friend of friend links. */




// Duplicating friend links because `vlookup.ado` would not link friends of friends id
forvalues i = 1(1)2 {

    gen mf`i'aid2 = mf`i'aid
    gen ff`i'aid2 = ff`i'aid

}   


/* 
Strategy: 1. use vlookup to attach the friend ids of each aid's friends,
          so for mf1aid it attaches that friend's mf1aid2, mf2aid2, ff1aid2, and ff2aid2
          2. delete self links in 2 link set
          3. delete own friends who are in 2 link set
          4. drop multiple listings in 2 link set to just 1 listing         

Mf_mf = "male friend male friend" so the male friends of i's male friends
Mf_ff = "male friend female friend"
Ff_mf = "female friend male friend"
Ff_ff = "female friend female friend"
*/  


// 1. Using vlookup.ado to link friends friend aids 
forvalues i = 1(1)2 {

    vlookup mf1aid, gen(Mf1_mf`i'aid) key(aid) value(mf`i'aid2)
    vlookup mf1aid, gen(Mf1_ff`i'aid) key(aid) value(ff`i'aid2)

    vlookup mf2aid, gen(Mf2_mf`i'aid) key(aid) value(mf`i'aid2)
    vlookup mf2aid, gen(Mf2_ff`i'aid) key(aid) value(ff`i'aid2)

    vlookup ff1aid, gen(Ff1_mf`i'aid) key(aid) value(mf`i'aid2)
    vlookup ff1aid, gen(Ff1_ff`i'aid) key(aid) value(ff`i'aid2)

    vlookup ff2aid, gen(Ff2_mf`i'aid) key(aid) value(mf`i'aid2)
    vlookup ff2aid, gen(Ff2_ff`i'aid) key(aid) value(ff`i'aid2)
}

drop mf1aid2-ff2aid2


// 2. Now Delete self links in friend of friend links
forvalues i = 1(1)2 {

    replace Mf1_mf`i'aid = . if Mf1_mf`i'aid == aid
    replace Mf2_mf`i'aid = . if Mf2_mf`i'aid == aid

    replace Ff1_mf`i'aid = . if Ff1_mf`i'aid == aid
    replace Ff2_mf`i'aid = . if Ff2_mf`i'aid == aid

}


// 3. Delete friends of friends who are also friends of i
forvalues i = 1(1)2 {

    replace Mf1_mf`i'aid = . if Mf1_mf`i'aid == mf1aid | Mf1_mf`i'aid == mf2aid     
    replace Mf1_ff`i'aid = . if Mf1_ff`i'aid == ff1aid | Mf1_ff`i'aid == ff2aid

    replace Mf2_mf`i'aid = . if Mf2_mf`i'aid == mf1aid | Mf2_mf`i'aid == mf2aid     
    replace Mf2_ff`i'aid = . if Mf2_ff`i'aid == ff1aid | Mf2_ff`i'aid == ff2aid

    replace Ff1_mf`i'aid = . if Ff1_mf`i'aid == mf1aid | Ff1_mf`i'aid == mf2aid     
    replace Ff1_ff`i'aid = . if Ff1_ff`i'aid == ff1aid | Ff1_ff`i'aid == ff2aid

    replace Ff2_mf`i'aid = . if Ff2_mf`i'aid == mf1aid | Ff2_mf`i'aid == mf2aid     
    replace Ff2_ff`i'aid = . if Ff2_ff`i'aid == ff1aid | Ff2_ff`i'aid == ff2aid

}
```

Here is the step I am stuck on. Because some of each person's friends share other friends I am now left 2 link peers showing up more than once for each respondent.

```
// 4. Replace multiple listings of 2 link peers



global mfofs "Mf1_mf1aid Mf1_mf2aid Mf2_mf1aid Mf2_mf2aid Ff1_mf1aid Ff2_mf2aid"
global ffofs "Mf1_ff1aid Mf1_ff2aid Mf2_ff1aid Mf2_ff2aid Ff1_ff1aid Ff2_ff2aid"




putmata aid Z=(Mf1_mf1aid Mf1_mf2aid Mf2_mf1aid Mf2_mf2aid Ff1_mf1aid Ff2_mf2aid Mf1_ff1aid Mf1_ff2aid Mf2_ff1aid Mf2_ff2aid Ff1_ff1aid Ff2_ff2aid) 

mata: 

/*
fofa = Z
for (i=1; i<=rows(Z); i++) {
    row = fofa[i,]'
    nvals[i] = length(uniqrows(select(row, (row :< .))))
}
*/


// The below is all sorts of wrong
fof = J(rows(Z), cols(Z), .)
 for (i=1; i<=rows(Z); i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=cols(Z); j++) {
        for (k=1; k<=cols(Z); k++) {
            if (Z[i,j] - Z[i,j+k] !=0) Z[i,j] = Z[i,j] 
        }
    }
}



end
```

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

I have seen an `egen` function from `egenmore` called `rownvals()`. However, it only returns values that do not repeat. I need to keep the first expression of the value and then set to missing the repeats.

If I have explained this poorly, then I apologize and please let me know where it is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Danielle has suggested, working with data in long form is usually much simpler.

What is desired is a list of friends of friends. And those in the list can't be first-level friends. In the sample data, for `aid == 101`, the only friend of `102` that is not `101` or a first-level friend of `101` is `104`.

In the code below, I use `rangejoin` (from SSC) to pair each observation's friend with their friends.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(aid mf1aid mf2aid ff1aid ff2aid)
101 102 103 106   .
102 101 104 106   .
103 101 104 107 108
104 105 102 108 109
105 104 101 106 110
106 101 102 107 108
107 103   . 106 110
108 103 104 109 108
109 104 101 108 110
110 105 104 109 107
end

* convert to long form
rename aid id
reshape long @aid, i(id) j(mfn) string
drop if mi(aid)
drop mfn
isid id aid, sort

* save each id's list of friends
save "friends.dta", replace

* first level of friends
rename aid friend1

* pair each observation with using obs where id is the same as friend1 in current obs
rangejoin id friend1 friend1 using "friends.dta"
rename aid friend2
drop *_U friend1

* remove self and duplicates
drop if id == friend2
bysort id friend2: keep if _n == 1

* remove those are are first level friends
rename friend2 aid
merge 1:1 id aid using "friends.dta", keep(master) nogen
```

Comment: Robert this by far more efficient than my approach and thanks @Danielle. However, I need true peers of peers meaning those separated by 2 links. For the set of nodes {i,j,k} where i is linked to j and j linked to k but i and k are not linked I need k as the friend2 of i not j and k. So, for friend2 those who also appear under friend1 must be set to missing or dropped. I am working on this now. If I figure it out, then I will note the change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is even simpler. I've adjusted the code accordingly. In the end, you find the friends of friends and then simply keep those that do not match first-level friends.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and your approach works great. I would up-vote your answer but apparently I'm not allowed to yet.

Comment: I've never asked a question on this forum so I don't know what's available to you but I believe that you have the option to "accept" my answer. According to the help: "Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question."

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing all these variables in a row (it seems so from the code and naming you have used), perhaps you could reshape this to a long dataset and then use one of the duplicate commands to mark or eliminate duplicates.

Note: this should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have the reputation to do that...